# Is there a way to make send mail as one line using formatdate and sendemail function

Tags: google-apps-script

Here is a snippet from my script:

```
  var formail = Utilities.formatDate(duedate, "yyyy/ MM/ dd");
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    docowner, // 메일 수신자
    "Document Integration Committee의 평가 due date", 
    "hello.\n" + place + code + 'of duedate' +formail + "is an day before" +before+"days. \nPlease check it."
  );
```

The problem is that in the email that gets sent, **place + code + 'of duedate' +formail + "is an day before" +before+"days.** gets split to two lines, like this:

```
New york 123 of duedate
is an day before 7 days.
```

The desired result is that the message body would not have a line break before `is`, like this:

```
New york 123 of duedate 2022/07/25 is an day before 7 days.
```

I used `\b` to escape, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `timezone` parameter in `Utilities.formatDate()`. Fix it like this:

```
  const timezone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() && SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone() || 'GMT';
  const dateString = Utilities.formatDate(duedate, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    docowner,
    'Document Integration Committee의 평가 due date',
    `hello.\n${place} ${code} of due date ${dateString} is a day before ${before} days.\nPlease check it.`
  );
```

Comment: thanks. I edited it, but it still expressed in two lines.

Comment: The code I gave you will insert newlines after `hello.` and `days`. To remove those newlines, remove the `\n`s. If you get a newline at some other point, it comes from one of the variables `place`, `code` or  `before`, and you need to check the definitions of those variables. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).